# authenticate_user error while writing posts ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0prHD.png)I've made an application that only authenticate_user can write post with ruby on rails.
but i have a little problem

case: if not logged in user try to access posts/new my app redirects to sign_in path really well but also shows the devise's error message.
i want to hide this error

Thanks for reading my question and have a nice day guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `devise.en.yml` file remove the error message, you need to change the error message to blank

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
```

Change the value of `unauthenticated` key to blank, it won't display the failure message if user tries to access a page that needs authentication.

```
unauthenticated: ""
```

Hope that helps!